# Datagridview does not showing data

Tags: c#, windows, binding, datagridview, gmail

I created one Windows application for displaying Gmail conversations in a datagrid. All are the items except Datagridview binding are working. I don't know what happened in Binding to the Gridview.. Please review my code snippet and give me a solution for resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.. My code is appending below...

```
  GmailItem _gItem = null;
            List<GmailItem> lstMail = new List<GmailItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mailCount; i++)
            {
                _gItem = new GmailItem();
                _gItem = client.GetMailItem(i);
                lstMail.Add(_gItem);
            }

            _bindingMails.DataSource = lstMail;
            dgMails.DataSource = _bindingMails;
```

And in designer page, this is the code for Datagridview

```
  this.dgMails.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgMails.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
        this.dgMails.Name = "dgMails";
        this.dgMails.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 150);
        this.dgMails.TabIndex = 0;
```

Also, i added this code in our .CS page

```
 dgMails.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dgMails.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Comment: What is the type of  `_bindingMails;` ?

Comment: @Rhapsody: BindingSource

Comment: I apologize for asking the equivalent of "Are you sure it's plugged in?" but, are you sure mailCount != 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides JonH's comment, I'd like to point out that your code would read better this way:

```
        List<GmailItem> lstMail = new List<GmailItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mailCount; i++)
        {
            lstMail.Add(client.GetMailItem(i));
        }

        _bindingMails.DataSource = lstMail;
        dgMails.DataSource = _bindingMails;
```

Answer (score 7):

1) Check that the BindingSource does not have a value for DataMember. The DataMember property tells the BindingSource to find a field/property with that name to get the IEnumerable from.

2) Make sure that `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` is True. This property is True by default and is not visible on a PropertyGrid, so you would have had to set it False in your code behind.

**Updated**

3) Does GMailItem contain public properties? Fields do not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need updating through the grid you could do:

```
dgMails.DataSource = lstMail; // Without the BindingSource
```

On the [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) they bind the BindingSource to the DataGrid *before* adding data to the BindingSource

Comment: is `dgMails.Autogeneratecolumns` set to true? (or did you set the `DataPropertyName` of each column?)